# object inheritance arugment input error

Tags: python-2.7, object, inheritance

Playing around with inheritance and came across an error stating that I am inputing too many arguments. What could I be doing wrong?

This first file is called media.py

```
class Video():
    def __init__(self, title, duration):
        self.title = title
        self.duration = duration

class Movie(Video):
    def __init__(self, movie_story, movie_poster, trailer_youtube):
        Video.__init__(self, title, duration)
        self.storyline = movie_story
        self.poster_image_url = movie_poster
        self.trailer_youtube_url = trailer_youtube

    def show_trailer(self):
        webbrowser.open(self.trailer_youtube_url)


class TvShow(Video):
    def __init__(self, season, episode, tv_station):
        Video.__init__(self, title, duration)
        self.season = season
        self.episode = episode
        self.tv_station = tv_station
```

This second file creates the objects.

```
import fresh_tomatoes
import media



family_guy = media.TvShow("Family Guy",
                            "2000-Present",
                            "Fifteen Seasons",
                            "Twenty-Eight",
                            "Fox")


print family_guy.title
```

The terminal output states I'm passing 6 arguments when only 4 may be accepted. Why is that?

Comment: Have you looked at the arguments you're passing and compared them to the constructor you defined?

Comment: @user2357112 well since Video is being inherited by TvShow shouldn't the order of the argument follow: title, duration, season, episode, tv_station?

Comment: No. Overridden constructors don't automatically inherit the arguments of the overridden form.

Comment: Then how would I go about inheriting from the Video class to the TvShow class?

Comment: Define your constructor to take all the arguments you want to pass it.

Comment: @user2357112 Ahh I see what you're saying. Took me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the parent `__init__` will only invoke it , but you still need to pass in the arguments to it.

So when you invoke `__init__` method for TvShow it only expects 3 +1(self) arguments , while you were trying to send more than that. So to solve the issue you just need to increase the number of arguments excepted by the `__init__`.

```
class Video():
    def __init__(self, title, duration):
        self.title = title
        self.duration = duration

class Movie(Video):
    def __init__(self, movie_story, movie_poster, trailer_youtube):
        Video.__init__(self, title, duration)
        self.storyline = movie_story
        self.poster_image_url = movie_poster
        self.trailer_youtube_url = trailer_youtube

    def show_trailer(self):
        webbrowser.open(self.trailer_youtube_url)


class TvShow(Video):
    def __init__(self, season, episode, tv_station, title, duration):
        Video.__init__(self, title, duration)
        self.season = season
        self.episode = episode
        self.tv_station = tv_station
```